# Faster way to search through a big string?

Tags: c#, performance, search

I am currently trying to make a program to find blocks of a specific color in a game save and move their position, however with some of the bigger saves my method of searching for the blocks in the save can start to take a bit. My current fastest method takes about 42 seconds to search for and move every block in a string about the size of 1MB. There are a lot of blocks in the save (Roughly one every 50-300 characters in the string, with a total of around 7k) so I'm not sure if string search algorithms would speed up or slow down this process.

So, I was wondering if I could get **any tips** of if anyone had any ideas on how to further **speed up my code** I would be very greatfull.

```
progressBar2.Maximum = blueprint.Length;
int i = 0;
while (i < blueprint.Length - 15)
{
   progressBar2.Value = i;
   try 
   { 
        if (!blueprint.Substring(i, 110).ToLower()
            .Contains("\"color\"")) 
        {
            i += 100; 
        } 
   } 
   catch 
   { 
      return; 
   }
   checkcolor(i, color, colortf, posset, axis);
   i++;
                
}
```

I am currently optimizing the method `checkcolor` and it's the cause for most of the delay, but my current method runs it way more than needed.

I've tried adding a second if to skip at an interval of 10 as well as 100 but that caused it to take over 2 min, I've also tried different values to skip other then 100 but 100 seems to be the fastest.

**Edit:** I was making 2 new temporary strings just to check for a small bit of text millions of times, it's a lot faster to use `.IndexOf` which I did not know existed. Thanks for the help and sorry if this was off topic.

Comment: Creating 2 new temporary strings (plus exception handling) just to check if there is the text `"color"` in a line is quite wasteful, you should take a look at `.IndexOf` instead

Comment: @MickyD: Neither of those posts categorize this question as off-topic.

Comment: @MickyD None of the answers in those Meta questions support your assertion/conclusion that "questions about _code optimisations_ are off-topic".  That Code Review might be a better place to ask an optimization question does not mean Stack Overflow is a bad or unacceptable place to ask the same question.  Though this question, in its current state, might be lacking or even off topic due to missing code/details, that the end-goal is optimizing code I don't think is enough, by itself, to make it off topic.

Comment: Questions about code optimization are [perfectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215282/is-stack-overflow-the-right-place-to-ask-a-question-about-code-efficiency) [fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help) here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"Neither of those posts categorize this question as off-topic"_ - perhaps, perhaps not.  But one thing is certain is that questions like these on SO generally lead to answers that are not [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and not _["backed up with facts and references"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_ as to why their solution offers any performance benefit - such as benchmarks.   So often I see up-voted answers to code optimisation improvement questions with zero metrics.  It is the onus of the author to state them.

Comment: @MickyD I am talking in general. We shouldn't dismiss questions automatically just because they ask to optimize some code. If this specific question has problems, then these specific problems should be pointed out so that the OP has the opportunity to fix them.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you so much, I did not know that existed even after spending like 2 hours looking this stuff up lol. This is exactly what I needed and now the times have gone down to under 20 seconds!

Comment: @JMO could you include in the question a minimalized example of some input, and the desirable output?

Comment: You could probably regex this string. Regex.Matches returns the position of all the matches found. You can set its Options to  `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`  and `RegexOptions.Compiled` -- Even better if you're using .Net 6+ -- It also makes it simple to remove the `try / catch` block (of course all matches are valid). -- There's the chance you can make parallel calls to `checkcolor()`.

Comment: @JMO - in general, it is best to keep data in smaller structures than long strings when you need to do fast comparisons. For example, putting the data in a collection of strongly typed class or struct would be far faster to search than finding within a string. If you have lots of data to search, you might be better off using binary serialization with a memory mapped file.

Comment: Yup I see now that such questions are not automatically off-topic.  I did find a good quote (my emphasis) _["Performance questions are on topic if they include a specific area of focus for improvement, can be answered with **facts/citations** (like specific **timings/memory analysis**), and such an answer would not be an unreasonable length (e.g. you could write an entire book on the topic)."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so#comment878044_412875)_.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to compare efficiency without creation substring and using `ToLower()`:

```
if (!blueprint.IndexOf("\"color\"", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: Brownie Points if you [include any form of benchmarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so#comment878044_412875).  Ready...set...go! ;)

Comment: No need for benchmarks. It's pretty obvious that `ToLower()` will cause significant performance issues due to GC.